# Qt, C++: GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon

Tags: c++, qt, gconf

I'm trying to make a form application under Arch Linux with Qt and C++, but when I try to run my application which is below:

#### firstWindow.h

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QLayout>

class firstWindow:public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        QLabel       *lbl;
        QPushButton  *btn;
        QLineEdit    *row;

    firstWindow():QMainWindow()
    {
        setWindowTitle("First Window");
        QWidget *win = new QWidget(this);
        setCentralWidget(win);

        lbl = new QLabel("Hello Universe", win);
        btn = new QPushButton("Click Click", win);
        row = new QLineEdit(win);

        QVBoxLayout *main = new QVBoxLayout(win);
        main->addWidget(win);

        QHBoxLayout *nextTo = new QHBoxLayout();
        nextTo->addWidget(row);
        nextTo->addWidget(btn);
        main->addLayout(nextTo);

        resize(200,50);
        win->show();
    }
};
```

After compiling it, I get this error:

```
#qmake -project
#qmake
#make
# ./QtFirstWindow
(process:21806): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

(process:21806): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

(process:21806): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Qt: Session management error: Authentication Rejected, reason : None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
```

It doesn't stop or kill the application, but it also doesn't run it. I think that error isn't about the code that I wrote, because it is a little sample. So how can I deal with that? Any idea?